# MySql Code for returning values in two tables for specific date then finding the difference of the two

Tags: mysql

Table 1 [image]

Table 2 [image]

I want to be able to return the spend for a particular day in table 1 (03/02/2019) minus the size * mean yield from table 2 for the same day. This is what I have;

SELECT spend FROM `Table 1` WHERE date LIKE '03/02/2019 %'

-

(SELECT size FROM `Table 2` WHERE date LIKE '03/02/2019 %'
*
 SELECT mean yield FROM `Table 2` WHERE date LIKE '03/02/2019 %')

I'm only starting out so apologies if this isnt the right way to post any of this, getting slightly confused.

Thanks so much for your time.

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables on the column `date`:

```
select t1.date, t1.spend - coalesce(t2.size * t2.meanyield, 0)
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t2.date = t1.date and t1.date = '2019-02-03'
```